# 'like' clause should be processed for the first 3 character of a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a scenario where I need to process 'like' clause of mysql for the first 3 character.

for example (table: emp)

```
----------------------
  name   |      dept  |
----------------------
John     |    finance |
Mickjohn |    finance |
Satheesh |    IT      |
Satheesh |    IT-ES   |
----------------------
```

This is what my table might looks like, Assume this would be my select query.

```
SELECT name from emp where name like '%jo';
```

This will return all the names which contains 'jo' regardless of this substring's position.
But What I want is, It should return names which are all contains 'jo' within first 5 characters.

In other words, **LIKE clause should processed the first 5 characters** of selected column. Is there anyway to do this?

For the above query default LIKE clause returns

```
---------
name     |
----------
john     |
Mickjohn |
---------
```

But I want it to return only

```
---------
name     |
----------
john     |
---------
```

Because 'john' only contains 'jo' within it's first 5 character.

Hope I explained well. I googled and found not enough to do so. Help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by using the [`LEFT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_left) function:

```
SELECT name FROM emp WHERE LEFT(name, 5) LIKE '%jo%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select name from emp where SUBSTRING(name, 1, 5) like '%jo%'
```